# Can the Airdrop service be accessed through MCNearbyServiceBrowser?

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

If so, what serviceType to initialize with?

I'm curious if one can write an app that would do something based on seeing Airdrop peers nearby.

Comment: I don't think so. They are two very different platforms, and for privacy reasons AirDrop (can be) limited. Nothing in either one's documentation references the other.

Comment: my understanding was that multipeer connectivity was generalized from AirDrop.. could be wrong though

I'd kind of expected that this wasn't possible, but there are lots of awesome things one could build if they did :(